# Display an image in VUE, that's being hosted on https

Tags: json, image, vue.js

I have a json that looks like this:

```
    {
    "books": [
        {
            "name": "Lord of the rings",
            "author": 1,
            "year": 1937,
            "genre": 3,
            "imageUrl": "https://cdn.lifehack.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/9780618640157_custom-s6-c30.jpg",
            "availability": true
        }
}
```

I'm trying to display the image like this: 
The problem is that the image is not being displayed, because the url is something like this localhost:8080/https://....
My code looks like this:

```
<tr v-for="item in items.books" :key="item.name">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   <td>{{item.author}}</td>
   <td>{{item.genre}}</td>
   <td><img :src="'{{'+item.imageUrl+'}}'"></td>
   <td>{{item.svailability}}</td>
</tr>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please show how does `<img>` tag inside your component look like?

Comment: Sure, my bad.
<img :src="'{{'+item.imageUrl+'}}'">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way: `<img :src="item.imageUrl">`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify more with some front-end code since this doesn't show us anything

**Update:**

Remove + from the brackets `{{'+item.imageUrl+'}}` like `{{item.imageUrl}}` 
You have a : in the src try `<img src="{{item.imageUrl}}"`

Comment: Yes, sorry.I forgot.

        <tr v-for="item in items.books" :key="item.name">
              <td>{{item.name}}</td>
              <td>{{item.author}}</td>
              <td>{{item.genre}}</td>
              <td><img :src="'{{'+item.imageUrl+'}}'"></td>
              <td>{{item.svailability}}</td>
        </tr>

Comment: Remove + from the brackets {{'+item.imageUrl+'} like {{item.imageUrl}}

Comment: You have a : in the src <img :src="'{{'+item.imageUrl+'}}'"></td>  needs to be <img src="'{{item.imageUrl}}'"></td>

Comment: Tried it and is still not working.Igor's version works, but thanks for your help.